# Protect int, only visible to specified methods

Tags: java, private, encapsulation

Is there a way that `i` is not visible to other methods within the same class?

```
private int i;

private void updateI(int i) {
  this.i = i;
}
```

Comment: don't make it global

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is clearly a XY question.

Comment: Note that naming your method `updateI` is not clever if you want to hide `i`...

Comment: @MarounMaroun Hiding the name of a private members to the coders writing methods in the same class ? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @dystroy, I disagree. One should always try to reduce the scope of a variable. OP is asking if there is a way to restrict the scope further than class-level private.

Answer (score 5):

No - *all* members of a class are visible to each other.

If you find that some members of your class shouldn't be accessing a particular member, that *may* indicate that you should split your class up - think about whether you could partition the information more finely, basically. That's not always a solution, of course - but certainly if you find that there are two or three fields that are related to each other, and that only some methods should touch, that's often an indication that you should put them in their own type.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such access modifier. Class level is the finest per-instance scope.

You might want to consider splitting up the state of the class in a separate class so that `i` can be a field of a smaller class.

**Example:**

```
class PositiveInt {
    int i;
    public void updateI(int i) {
        if (i < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);
        this.i = i;
    }
    // ...
}

class YourClass {

    // No need to worry about 'i' staying positive in a large and complex class
    PositiveInt i = new PositiveInt();

    void updateI(int newI) {
        i.updateI(newI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No ... private fields are only visible inside your class by all methods. 
You can inherit from this class to hide fields.

Answer (score 0):

Since `i` is a member variable of a class, it will be visible to other non-static methods. If you want its scope to be limited to a method, it cannot be a class member.

For a simple introduction to variable scope in Java, you can take a look at [this page](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want a class variable to be only visible to a specific method.

Just declare the variable within the method so it's only visibly to that method:

```
    private void updateI(int x) { 
      int i = x;
     }
```

Comment: That just creates an `i` for each method call, and not a single `i` attribute for the object.